# Session variables vs URL variables in terms of speed

Tags: php, performance, session, url

What are the speed comparisons between `$_SESSION` and URL variables? I'm currently working on a situation where either of the two is comparable - so I would like to take that as an opportunity to optimize speed.

URL seems faster as the information isn't carried on to other pages in the site, but what if I just unset the variable after use?

Edit: Thanks to user [ishegg](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8469069/ishegg) for pointing out, by URL variables I mean GET variables, such as the information from mywebsite.com?search=fruit

Edit2: According to comment section, $ and $_GET are essentially the same in speed - please use the marked duplicate if you are having the same issue

Note: I've seen [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3559655/when-to-use-url-session-cookie-variables) but the accepted answer doesn't explain why #1 is better than #2 in terms of speed. And [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23012748/php-url-query-string-parameters-vs-session-variables)'s answer was good but didn't compare speed either.

Comment: By URL variables you mean $_GET variables? Depending on implementation, $_SESSION values require I/O and possibly have network latency (if you're using a database to store them), so $_GET variables will be faster than $_SESSION variables

Comment: Yes that's what I meant - I should have included an example! That's a good answer thank you

Comment: When in doubt, run a benchmark.

Comment: @ishegg Do $_GET variables work the same as regular `$` variables? For example, would `$_GET['test']` be basically the same as `$test` in terms of speed? Ignoring the fact that the $_GET is actually an array.

Comment: This may be a near-duplciate to [PHP ::: Speed Test ::: $_SESSION vs. $variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9028765/php-speed-test-session-vs-variable) but I can't decide

Comment: Thanks @Fred-ii- :)

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton Not "near" but "is". Thanks for finding that. Edit: welcome.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I couldn't decide because this question specifically asks about `$_GET` variables, and not regular page variables.

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton there isn't much difference really.

Comment: This is a duplicate if Grumpy's question about $_GET vs $ is correct, but are they actually the same thing or is the information stored differently as it's accessed across pages? Edit: Thanks Fred for the clearup